# Using Free with a non-functor in Scalaz

Tags: scala, design-patterns, functional-programming, scalaz, algebraic-data-types

In the "FP in Scala" book there's this approach for using an ADT `S` as an abstract instruction set like

```
sealed trait Console[_]
case class PrintLine(msg: String) extends Console[Unit]
case object ReadLine extends Console[String]
```

and composing them with a `Free[S, A]` where `S` would later be translated to an IO monad.
Can this be done with Scalaz's `Free` type? It seems that all `run` methods require a functor instance for `S`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes, you need a functor, but you can create one using `Coyoneda`.

`Coyoneda` will turn any `F[A]` into a `Coyoneda[F,A]` and `Coyoneda[F,A]` is a functor.

```
scala> type ConsoleCoyo[A] = Coyoneda[Console, A]
defined type alias ConsoleCoyo
```

Then scalaz's Free has a type alias just for this:

```
/** A free monad over the free functor generated by `S` */
type FreeC[S[_], A] = Free[({type f[x] = Coyoneda[S, x]})#f, A]
```

So now We have a Free monad for console:

```
scala> type ConsoleMonad[A] = Free.FreeC[ConsoleCoyo,A]
defined type alias ConsoleMonad
```

also you'll find handy that scalaz's Free has a function to lift a F[A] directly into a monad:

```
/** A free monad over a free functor of `S`. */
def liftFC[S[_], A](s: S[A]): FreeC[S, A] =
  liftFU(Coyoneda lift s)
```

so, for example:

```
scala> Free.liftFC(ReadLine)
res1: scalaz.Free.FreeC[Console,String] = Suspend(scalaz.Coyoneda$$anon$22@360bb132)
```

Comment: One note: `FreeC` already `Coyoneda`s its first argument, so you'd just want `FreeC[Console, A]`, not `FreeC[ConsoleCoyo, A]`.